Can I use a global variable instead of a React.Context to pass constant props here?
I'm wondering what the disadvantages of a globally shared variable in favor of a Context are in my use case:

The value of this variable will be set once at first rendering
The value of this variable won't change during the runtime
The variable is required at many different places
The variable can be shared amongst all users

So it would look like this:
'use client'

...

const MyRootComponent: React.FC<{ rawEnvData: string }> = ({ rawEnvData }) => {
  setConstants(rawEnvData);
  ...
}

And constants.ts looks like this:
let constants: ReturnType<typeof createConstants> | undefined = undefined;

export const setConstants = (rawEnvData: string) => {
  if (!constants) {
    constants = createConstants(JSON.parse(rawEnvData));
  }
  return getConstants();
};

const getConstants = () => {
  if (!constants) throw Error('constants not defined');
  else return constants;
};

So, getConstants would be invoked at all places.
The advantage I'm aiming for: I'm not required to use the useContext hook and instad can access the constants without obeying the rule of hook.
The disadvantages coming to my mind are:

I could accidentally invoke getConstants() at a React Server Component or before MyRootComponent.
I could accidentally invoke getConstants() at a global level before it got initialized, e.g. with const myValue = getConstants().myValue at the top level of a file

Am I missing something, do I break with some principles which are out of question, or is that a way I could go?

Using a global variable means that your state is stored outside the React components lifecycle. It means that if you change the value of this variable during rendering and there are more then one component on the page that will render/use the value of this variable: this component won't be notified that value has been updated and will render inconsistant value. This can also be problematic for server-side rendering. depends on the enviroment: edge or self-hosted. variable will be shared for all sessions/users globally or randomly reinstantiated on every request. Even for client components which is still pre-renders on server if you call updateValue method not in the useEffect hook it will modify the value.
Better to stick with one of those:

Context
Environment Variables, if value is known on build time
runtime config for next

Upd: if none of the described concerns bothers you, variable can be shared between users, it will be updated once when app is initialized, and you not seeing any immediate errors, have it as global could be totally fine

Thank you for the response! In my case, the value won't change. And I cannot use env values here b/c have to go this route - the variable is basically an env but not known at build time.
What do you mean with it being problematic on server-side rendering - edge runtime shouldn't be an issue in my client component, right? Sharing between users is fine, it's basially data stemming from the env.
I just don't like the thought of hookify-ing all my logic just to pass those (effectively env) data via content.

"edge runtime shouldn't be an issue in my client component, should it?" well, client components (i assume we are talking about next.js) still pre-render on server. and if you call updateValue method not in the useEffect hook it will modify the value. but if it can be shared between users globally i guess it is not a problem. tbh, if none this concerns bothers you, and you not seeing any immediate errors, i guess have it as global could be totally fine :)

Yeah, talking about Next.js. I figure that tag is an info which is a bit easy to miss. ;)
Alright then, I figure I'll accept your answer. Since your "effective" answer comes from the latest comment, would you mind putting moving into the answer for reference?

yeah, for sure, will update my answer now
